# Magento 2 GetFinalPrice issue to fetch correct price

Tags: price, magento2.3.2

When passing the Id of Simple product then it's working fine but when passing the Id of child product then it's not working, It will not show the correct price of the product

Comment: please attach  your code

Comment: $product->getFinalPrice() // It is working but when find final price of child it is not working properly.Just like when sale price is smaller than product price it will give small price after cal.But it will give productPrice.
$child->getFinalPrice()

Answer (score 0):

You can get the regular price and special price for all types of product in following way:

> 1. Simple Product

```
$regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getValue();
$specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('special_price')->getValue();
```

> 2. Bundle product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'bundle') {
      $regularPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('final_price')->getMinimalPrice()->getValue();            
}
```

> 3. Configurable Product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'configurable') {
      $basePrice = $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');

      $regularPrice = $basePrice->getMinRegularAmount()->getValue();
      $specialPrice = $product->getFinalPrice();
}
```

> 4. Grouped product

```
if ($product->getTypeId() == 'grouped') {
      $usedProds = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getAssociatedProducts($product);            
      foreach ($usedProds as $child) {
          if ($child->getId() != $product->getId()) {
                $regularPrice += $child->getPrice();
                $specialPrice += $child->getFinalPrice();
          }
      }
}
```

In above code, `$product` refers to the object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product`.